# Use a relative file URI in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, uri

I want to have a comment in my code that opens another source file relative to the current source file like this:

```
// To add new settings, edit file:///../../../stagedata/settings.csv
```

But it seems VS Code is interpreting all URIs relative to the root of the drive. I also tried to figuire out how to use an environment variable in the path like:

```
// To add new settings, edit file:///%25APPDIR%25/stagedata/settings.csv
```

But the percents are included in the path as literals and the file is still not found.
It works great if I put the full path, but the directory name will be different on each developer's machine.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Your file URI looks like `file:///...`, i.e., it's absolute (decompose it as `file` + `://` + `/...`. No idea, whether it'd work when you left out the slash.

Comment: @maaartinus If you only have 2 slashes in a file URI, the host name must go between the "file://" and the next "/".

Comment: I guess, you're right. You can imagine why I hate URLs.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make this work?

Soon it seems, but I think the answer is not until now [except for this work around](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/199030#issuecomment-1863027430):

> Open file from Frank Stuetzer
> You can write relative path directly in the comment (ex: // ../my-file.js;) and when the comment is focused, you can do Alt+P on Windows or Option+P on Mac) to go to the targeted file.
>
> Not optimal but does the work.

Else [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/199030#issuecomment-1863751155) ticket:

> This feature request received a sufficient number of community upvotes and we moved it to our backlog. To learn more about how we handle feature requests, please see our documentation.